# Is it possible to not use Windows Authentication w/ a SQL Server Filestream store and using streaming access to a file within it?

Tags: filestream

Everything I've seen and experienced so far suggests that you must use Windows Authentication if you want to access a file via Win32 from within the a databases filestream store but is it possible to use jsut SQL authentication somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to use Windows Authentication.

See the official team Web Log for Microsoft Customer Service and Support (CSS) SQL Support:

[How It Works: File Streams Requires Integrated Security (Windows Authentication)](http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2008/04/10/how-it-works-file-streams-requires-integrated-security-windows-authentication.aspx)